# Can't make 2 divs to sit side by side

Tags: html, css

I cant Make this 2 divs to sit side by side ,There is some white space between them,and if i add one more px on width the one in the right goes below the one in the left.
I think maybe i nested the divs wrong i am not sure , i know this is something simple but i dont know what i did wrong ...

```css
*{margin:0px;
padding:0px;}

body{background-color:white;}

h3{float:left;
color:white;
padding-left:160px;
padding-top:11px;
font-family:cursive;}

ul{list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#00b7b7; 
overflow:hidden;
width:276px;
float:right;
height:47px;}

li a{display:block;
width:60px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding:14px 16px;
height:47;}

li{display:inline;
float:right;}

li a:hover{background-color:#0c6d6d;}
li a:link{color:White;}
li a:visited{color:white;}

.header{background-color:#0193C4;
width:100%;
height:47px;
overflow:hidden;}


.left{width:1072px;
height:350px;
background-color:#0193C4;
float:left;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;}

.right{width:277px;
height:270px;
background-color:#00b7b7;
float:right;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;}


ul:first-child{border-left-style: solid;
border-color:black;}

.container{margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>project1</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="project1.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
<h3>WebSite</h3>

<div class="navbar">
         <ul>
                  <li>    <a href="#">        Menu  </a></li>      
      <li>    <a href="#">       Contact </a></li> 
      <li>  <a href="#">        Help  </a></li>       
          </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<p></p>
</div>

<div class="right">
<p></p>

</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all..?

Comment: @Lee I have tried everything i know ...

Comment: .container have some margin. Disable it.

Comment: Then show us examples of what you've tried.  Just curious, if you float them both left... what happens?

Comment: @SkyWookie that won't affect the child divs

Comment: @OneBeginer, on the class .right remove float right, and add float: left

Comment: @Lee If i float both left is the same thing, remains some white space on the right and if i add px to the width it goes below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `percentage units` or `vw units` for your boxes, and `float:left` for both of them:

```css
*{margin:0px;
padding:0px;}

body{background-color:white;}

h3{float:left;
color:white;
padding-left:160px;
padding-top:11px;
font-family:cursive;}

ul{list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#00b7b7; 
overflow:hidden;
width:276px;
float:right;
height:47px;}

li a{display:block;
width:60px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding:14px 16px;
height:47;}

li{display:inline;
float:right;}

li a:hover{background-color:#0c6d6d;}
li a:link{color:White;}
li a:visited{color:white;}

.header{background-color:#0193C4;
width:100%;
height:47px;
overflow:hidden;}


.left{width:70%;
height:350px;
background-color:#0193C4;
float:left;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;}

.right{width:30%;
height:270px;
background-color:#00b7b7;
float:left;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;}


ul:first-child{border-left-style: solid;
border-color:black;}

.container{margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h3>WebSite</h3>

<div class="navbar">
         <ul>
                  <li>    <a href="#">        Menu  </a></li>      
      <li>    <a href="#">       Contact </a></li> 
      <li>  <a href="#">        Help  </a></li>       
          </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<p></p>
</div>

<div class="right">
<p></p>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This Works , Thank You very much, but why dosent works in px ?

Comment: This works well for responsive layouts. But generally, you need to have right width of container.

Comment: It is not safe to use pixel in this case, because of the windows screen sizes. If you want to create a responsive layout, you should use percentage units, lately vw(viewport width) units are very useful too.So, if you use these units, your layout fits very good in small screen size divices. @OneBeginer

Answer (score 1):

Your container is not wide enought to fit childs!

```
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 2000px; /* do your calc here */
}
```